# same functionality can we get it without writing filteredMessages function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Same functionality can we get it without writing filteredMessages function..
since I wanted to have only this function alone..

I am working on simple js function...
GetShortMessages takes an array of objects with `.message` properties and returns an array of messages that are less than < 50 characters long.
Providing my code below in the fiddle.. Basically I am trying to learn functions in js..

http://jsfiddle.net/98f87za2/

```
function filteredMessages(messages){
        return messages.length < 50;
}

function getShortMessages(messages) {
// SOLUTION GOES HERE
    var filtered = messages.filter(filteredMessages);
    return filtered;
}

module.exports = getShortMessages
```

Answer (score 3):

As [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method expect callback function as param you can get rid of `filteredMessages` only by using anonymous function:

```
var filtered = messages.filter( function(messages) {
    return messages.length < 50;
});
```